# Summation of a series $ \sum_{r=0}^{10} \frac{3^{r} (r!(3r^2 + 5r +1))}{r^2 + 3r +2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I dont know where to start in this question. I tried finding partial fractions for the expression but reached nowhere.

Any hints would be Appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Let
$$\dfrac{3r^2+5r+1}{(r+1)(r+2)}=3A-A+3\cdot\dfrac B{r+2}-\dfrac B{r+1}$$

so that $$\frac{3^{r} (r!(3r^2 + 5r +1))}{r^2 + 3r +2}$$ can be expressed as $$f(r+1)-f(r)$$ to use Telescoping Series.